# Creating a dictionary from a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, loops, csv, file, dictionary

I'm a beginner in python and I'm stuck on my program.

I would like to create a program that extracts data from the CSV file and displays the following result when it runs :

**{company: [total number of missions, number of successful missions, number of failed missions]}**

I started to write a code but I think I made mistakes. Can someone help me with this program?

```
with open ('data-files/SpaceMission_data.csv', 'r') as handle:
    content = csv.reader(handle)
    print(content)
-------------------------------------------------(new cell)----------------------------------------
import csv

def space_statistics(filename):
    '''The function returns a dictionary in which it counts the number of mission for each company in charge
    and also counts the number of successful and failed missions'''

    space = dict()
    err_Msg = 'Error: Check the file path or content' 
 
    # TYPE YOUR CODE HERE.
    
      try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as handle:
            for line in handle:
                val = line.split(",")[1:7]
                print(val)
                space[val[1]] = int(val[7]) 
                print(msg.format(val[1], val[7]))
            
        return space
                                     
    except:
        print("Error: Something wrong with your file location?")
        return

help(space_statistics)
```

Here is a screenshot of the 'SpaceMission_data.csv' file. [image: screen]

Comment: instead of screenshot can you please add csv data as string to question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leverage the csv module then you can just index the data easily. Check if the key is there if it is just access the last entry otherwise add a new list.

```
import csv

def space_statistics(csvFile):
    space = {}
    with open(csvFile, newline='') as inFile:
        reader = csv.reader(inFile)
        data = list(reader)
    for entry in data[1:]:#skip the first one because thats the header
        if entry[2] in space:#company already exists in dict
            if entry[-1] == 'Success'
                space[entry[2]][1] += 1
            else:#failed
                space[entry[2]][2] += 1
            space[entry[2]][0] += 1#total mission count
        else:
            space[entry[2]] = [1,0,0]
            if entry[-1] == 'Success'
                space[entry[2]][1] += 1
            else:#failed
                space[entry[2]][2] += 1
    return space
```

Comment: Ok I'll try, thank you for your time ! I'm coming back asap.